# Fatal error Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Estaba realizando unos cambios en mi pagina de wordpres, estaba actualizando un plugin y no se guardaban mis actualizaciones. Luego me intente volver a meter en el administrador de mi pagina, y me salio lo siguiente:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by
>   (output started at
>   /home/content/67/8651767/html/rfoods/wp-content/plugins/a-sub-site-teaser-widget/a-sub-site-teaser-widget.php:1)
>   in /home/content/67/8651767/html/rfoods/wp-includes/pluggable.php on
>   line 1228

¿Alguien me puede decir como arreglarlo?

PS: Trabajo con una mac

Comment: Aca esta una respuesta en ingles que puede ayudar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php

Comment: Esto ocurre porque estás intentando cambiar alguna información en el header (por ejemplo, haciendo un redirección) cuando ya se ha escrito algo en la página y eso no está permitido

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos razones comunes para este error, aunque no se agotan aquí, son las más fáciles de diagnosticar.

Usualmente ocurre porque uno de los archivos requeridos por WordPress, ya sea de temas o de plugins, está emitiendo texto aunque parezca increíble, solo por tener caracteres fuera de las etiquetas

Para evitar esto, primero debes verificar que **ningún archivo** de PHP, tenga la etiqueta de cierre `?>` al final. Eso quiere decir que no debes tener salida de HTML, ni de espacios en blanco (incluso un simple salto de línea cuenta como espacio en blanco), después del cierre. Por eso lo más sencillo es que ningún archivo de funciones del tema o plugins, tenga el cierre `?>` al final, ya que este solo lo necesitas, cuando después deseas poner HTML o texto en el navegador, pero justamente eso es lo que genera el error que ves.

La segunda es un poco más complicada y depende mucho de que el editor de texto que estés usando, no te traicione y ponga caracteres (invisibles) antes de la etiqueta `<?php`, por tu mensaje de error: `output started at ... a-sub-site-teaser-widget/a-sub-site-teaser-widget.php: 1` justo ese parece ser el caso **¿qué tienes en la línea 1 de ese archivo?**.

El [enlace sugerido por Wilfredo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1912029/warning-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by-error) tiene más casos, pero en esencia es lo que te indico, y casi con seguridad tu editor está metiendo marcas invisibles antes del código PHP y por eso el error. En específico puede que tengas que localizar el "Byte Order Mark", y [esta página](http://www.cristalab.com/tutoriales/eliminar-bom-para-validar-tu-pagina-web-c77349l/) (con un consejo para Mac) puede que tenga la solución práctica que estás buscando.

Answer (score 0):

Mientras investigas la causa raíz del problema, lo inmediato sería desactivar el plugin para poder entrar al panel.

Para forzar la desactivación puedes eliminar los archivos del plugin que tira el error y wordpress lo dará por desactivado. Luego puedes volver a agregarlos e ir probando.